# cmake - how to find out options used during last build

Tags: cmake

I would like to use an example: I have now downloaded mariadb and compiled it from source and everything works fine.

Let's say, in six months or so, I download the new version and want to build it. How can I find out which options I have set during last build?

Or can I adopt the settings from last build for the new version somehow?

Comment: There's a file named CMakeCache.txt inside the build folder, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yes, there is. But it is not visible, which options other than default have been set. I expect I have to run cmake without any options in the new directory and afterwards diff the two files (or create a log by hand).